# How can I debug a constantly losing focus window (dialog, for instance) in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I am maintaining I big and mature application, without background on MFC paradigm and layout. I have experience with Qt, OO designs and UI frameworks (I'm aware of each thread responsibility, event loops, event handling hierarchies, etc.

I'm stuck with a settings CDialog window losing focus constantly, while I'm trying to configure my application. I also have a file explorer dialog that behaves exactly the same way. Both are activated by DoModal calls.

I've read that this is probably because I have two modal dialogs competing for focus. How can I debug that? What function could I break on to get a helpful callstack, so I can find the offending code? Is there an `MFC::focusWindow(WHND window)` or something that I could intercept?

Comment: If it is anything to do with focus, try debugging remotely instead of locally.  That way you won't get confused between the debugger taking focus and the dialog losing focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem according to your description is that you 'have two modal dialogs competing for focus'. This should normally not be possible because by definition a modal dialog takes over the application and does not return control to its launch point until the dialog is closed.  Without knowing the architecture of the application, the simplest solution would be to make the settings dialog modeless (create it then call ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) instead of DoModal.  This will allow the message loop to run for the other modal dialog but not take focus from your settings dialog unless it is doing it explicitly in its own methods.

Comment: I will try that, at least to try to find what is the focus thief window. I'm build for Windows, it's a desktop application. I'm afraid that the main window (there is only one and then the modals) is being opened as modal.

Comment: Actually, no window is getting the focus, at least none that I can see.

Comment: Then you can take the focus manually by setting it in the InitDlg message handler which fires after the window is created but before it appears on the screen so all of the control objects exist at that point. m_MyButton.setFocus();  The main form window is the parent of any dialogs and the message handling should defer to any open child windows.  Are the dialogs being correctly created as children of the main window ?

Comment: The window still loses the focus, I just don't see what other window gets it. If I click the modal dialog, it gets the focus for half a second or so and loses again, no other apparent window receiving it.

Comment: Without seeing the code its difficult to know what could cause this.  But something else is running a message loop and creating an active window that is taking or being given the focus in the code.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right. Sorry for being too vague. I'm giving you the right answer flag, since yours tackled the problem more throughly.

Answer (score 1):

Use Spy++ to spy the messages/events that occurring in the dialog.

Comment: Not accepting this yet, but thank you very much for sharing this. Spy++ seems to be what I need to understand the behavior and interactions of the UI elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SetFocus function, please refer to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `Remarks

The SetFocus function sends a WM_KILLFOCUS message to the window that loses the keyboard focus and a WM_SETFOCUS message to the window that receives the keyboard focus. It also activates either the window that receives the focus or the parent of the window that receives the focus.`
I should probably break on the `WM_SETFOCUS` message instead of on the `SetFocus` function. `SetFocus` seems to be a high level API that uses those messages to actually achieve the desired effect.